# Custom Preference With Radio Button Issue

Tags: android, radio-button, preference

Im planning to create app start with splash screen depend on user preference ( final goal, still not add onclick listener to buttons ) , i start step by step to achieve that and its first time to use radio buttons in preference ,

when i run app and press preference button in option menu  it gave force close as below code .

I know it can be done through listpreference in preference.xml in xml folder , but id like to do it in layout if that is possible.

any help will be appreciated , thanks

**Splash.java**

```
 public class Splash extends Activity {
MediaPlayer ourSong;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

     ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splashsound);          
        ourSong.start();            
        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(2000); 
                    }
                  catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                    }
                  finally{
                      Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);                                     
                        startActivity(intent); 
                        }
                } 
            };                                                                         
             timer.start();
             }      
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        ourSong.release();
        finish();
              } 
           }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {

MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.cool_menu, menu);

getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {

if (name .equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")) {
try {
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
final View view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);

new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
public void run() {

((TextView) view).setTextSize(25);  
((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.RED); 
} 
}
);                                        
return view;
}
 catch (InflateException e) {        
 }
  catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {          
  }
}                                  
return null; 
}
}
);           
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);                                    
}   
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.aboutUs:
        Intent i = new Intent("com.example.custompreference.ABOUT");
        startActivity(i);
    break;
    case R.id.preferences:
        Intent p = new Intent("com.example.custompreference.PREFS");
        startActivity(p);
    break;
    case R.id.exit:
        finish();
    break;
}
return false;
}
}
```

**Prefs.java**

```
  public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity{    
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pref);
    }
    }
```

**pref.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
  <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:gravity="center">    

<RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_first"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="First"
    android:textColor="#B22222"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

<RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_second"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Second"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.custompreference"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.custompreference.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
       android:name=".MainActivity" 
       android:label="@string/app_name" >           
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.example.custompreference.MAINACTIVITY" />                
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>

    <activity 
       android:name=".AboutUs" 
       android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.example.custompreference.ABOUT" />                
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>

    <activity 
       android:name=".Prefs" 
       android:label="@string/app_name" >           
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.example.custompreference.PREFS" />               
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
  </application>
  </manifest>
```

**LOGCAT:**

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
 ComponentInfo{com.example.custompreference/com.example.custompreference.Prefs}:
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is  
  'android.R.id.list'
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id 
    attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)      
  atandroid.preference.PreferenceActivity.onContentChanged(PreferenceActivity.java:165)       
at om.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:219)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1660)
at com.example.custompreference.Prefs.onCreate(Prefs.java:11)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look through the logcat you can see that you need a ListView.

But you're going at this all wrong. You should basically create a Preferences.xml file in which you specify which preference widgets you want in your PreferenceActivity, e.g. RadioButtons, and then assign that xml file to your PreferenceActivity like this:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

Example of Preferences.xml from [this tutorial](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/creating-a-preference-activity-in-android/) (file goes in res/xml folder which you should create yourself)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <PreferenceCategory
   android:summary="Username and password information"
   android:title="Login information" >
  <EditTextPreference
     android:key="username"
     android:summary="Please enter your login username"
     android:title="Username" />
  <EditTextPreference
     android:key="password"
     android:summary="Enter your password"
     android:title="Password" />
 </PreferenceCategory>

 <PreferenceCategory
   android:summary="Username and password information"
   android:title="Settings" >
  <CheckBoxPreference
     android:key="checkBox"
     android:summary="On/Off"
     android:title="Keep me logged in" />

  <ListPreference
     android:entries="@array/listOptions"
     android:entryValues="@array/listValues"
     android:key="listpref"
     android:summary="List preference example"
     android:title="List preference" />
 </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

So take a look [here](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/creating-a-preference-activity-in-android/)

Edit:

You can add a custom entry to the ListView in Preferences.xml like this:

```
    <Preference
        android:layout="@layout/your_custom_pref_entry"
        android:key="SOME_KEY_NAME" />
```

Not sure how to handle the RadioButtons selection from there though.

Comment: i know that to create preference.xml in xml folder and that list preference will give the radiobuttons but i want to do it through layout and able to customize it , is this possible my dear .thanks